# Compile libfaketime 64 bit in solaris11

Tags: 64-bit, solaris

I just tried to build libfaketime 64 bit in solaris11 and succeeded, while it just doesn’t work.

base guideline:
http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/faketime/index.xp?show_selected=1&msgid=426#feedback_form

Anyone has a successful experience?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to set export `LD_PRELOAD_64=/full/path/libraryfile`  in order for it to work.  As well as exporting FAKE_TIME_OFFSET or FAKE_TIME_START.  If you did this it will work - running a 64 bit image.
32 bit image file - no.

```
file exeIwantToRun
```

Has to indicate a 64 bit file.  Try it with the date command.